# Extract image with preg_match_all Function

Tags: php, image

i have a problem with preg_match_all, this is a function from my PHPfile:

```
function get_images ($content){

  preg_match_all ('#\\[img\\](.+?)\\[/img\\]#ie', $content, $preg_array);
  if (count ($preg_array[1]) != 0){
    foreach ($preg_array[1] as $item){
        if ($this->reset_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])!=$this->reset_url($item)){
            if (!(in_array ($item, $this->images))){
                $this->images[] = $item;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

with that code, i can extract images only from simple [img][/img] tag, example:

```
[img]http://www.domain.com/image.jpg[/img]
```

i cant use img tag with align, example:

```
[img=left]http://www.domain.com/image.jpg[/img]
```

how i can fix this function to use both image tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this,

```
preg_match_all ('#\\[img.*\\](.+?)\\[/img\\]#ie', $content, $preg_array);
```

[Codeviper Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/g0eZIv)

Answer (score 3):

```
#\[img(:?.*)?\](.*?)\[/img\]#
```

This will ignore whatever is in `[img=foo]` and only take the source info.